# When ngif from scrollDispatcher, the variable not working

Tags: angular, subscribe

In angular, I use scrollDispatcher(checking scrolling) change variable flag at html DOM, but the DOM(ngif) not work, there is my testing code:

```
// html
<div *ngIf="scrollState">
  scrolling!
</div>

// TS
import { ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
...
scrollState = false;
...
constructor( private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher){
    let self = this;
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe( function () {
      self.scrollState = true;
      console.log('now scrolling!', self.scrollState ); 
      //checking scrollState, it's true
    });
}
```

When I scrolling, the DOM is not show, but I checking self.scrollState is really true, why? I can't understand, please help me, thank you.

## Specific example

```
//html
<div class="sectionStickyTitle" *ngIf="sectionStickyTitleState">
  <h2>Test new title</h2>
</div>

<h1 class="section-h1" #sectionh1>I'm check top target</h1>

//TS
import { ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
...
@ViewChild('sectionh1') sectionh1: ElementRef;
sectionStickyTitleState = false;
sectionhOffsetTop: number;
...
constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher, ...){
}

ngOnInit(){
 ...
 this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe(() => this.setSectionStickyTitle());
}

...
setSectionStickyTitle() {
  this.sectionhOffsetTop = this.sectionh1.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  this.sectionStickyTitleState = (this.sectionhOffsetTop <= 21) ? true : false;

  console.log('sectionStickyTitleState --> ', this.sectionStickyTitleState);
  console.log('sectionhOffsetTop --> ', this.sectionhOffsetTop);
}
```

I re-edited the problem, the purpose is the same, the flag can not be recognized by html, when the height of #sectionh1 is less than 21, flag must be true, it is also true, but *ngIf="sectionStickyTitleState"(flag) always unable to respond.

This really makes me hard to understand because console.log always means flag is true.

Comment: can you give some more detail about what exactly you want to do? do you want to capture scroll events on a certain element or any element in DOM or just document/window? also what are you going to do when you handle the event?

Comment: @ysf Hi, I re-edited my question, the specific example has more  details. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#ScrollDispatcher)

> in order to avoid hitting change detection for every scroll event, all
>   of the events emitted from this stream will be run outside the Angular
>   zone. If you need to update any data bindings as a result of a scroll
>   event, you have to run the callback using NgZone.run.

so, do as follows;

```js
constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher, private zone: NgZone){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe(() => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.setSectionStickyTitle();
    });
  });
}
```

i also created a demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msn4ma

in demo above when you scroll `body` or `div1` template bindings update properly. but if you scroll `div2` template bindings doesn't update even though it prints the console.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your precise explanation, it really works, I will remember it, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

There are few changes I would suggest in your code, use this instead of let and use an arrow function

```
constructor( private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher){
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe() => {
      this.scrollState = true;
      console.log('now scrolling!', this.scrollState ); 
    });
}
```

Comment: thank's, I change an arrow, but ngif still not working :(

Comment: try {{scrollState}} on html and see

Comment: In fact, it is not the original purpose to react when scrolling. I originally had the offsetTop to judge other DOMs, but it also didn't work, so I just wanted to confirm if there are other possibilities. It's like " if(offset <= number), flag = true/false ...", so I can't just rely on scrollstate :(